# PCManFM-Qt is not default file manager in Lubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: lubuntu, lxqt

`PCManFM-Qt` works fine, but when I want to lunch "open this folder" in digikam or `directorymenu` plugin on lxqt-panel, doublecmd-qt app is runinng instead of pcmanfm-qt. I spend many hours trying to fix this problem. Reinstall package pcmanfm-qt does not solve this problem. Apt Purge doublecmd-qt sets firefox as default file manager!

LxQt seems to have no place when I can choose default file manager.

These are steps to reproduce it. I was reproduced it in Virtualbox on clear install.

- Install Lubuntu 20.04 (and apt update & upgrade)
- **Chose use "LxQt Desktop" instead of "Lubuntu" on login screen**
- install doublecmd-qt and problem happens.

Comment: `pcmanfm-qt` is the default file manager in Lubuntu & LXQt  (what the *fm* stands for, though it handles more than just *fileman* functions)  You can change default associations with the *Alternatives Configurator* (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.17/alternative_configurator.html) however that may not be a fix with that (i have no options there for xubuntu(xfce)/ubuntu(gnome) either so I'm missing something most probably.  (my own Lubuntu opens `pcmanfm-qt` when I click *open-in-folder* but I don't use `digikam`)

Comment: FYI:   I `apt install digikam` on both a *focal* (20.04.1) & *groovy* (20.10) QA-test [daily] *fresh* installs & both *Open in File Manager* from `digikam` opened `pcmanfm-qt` for me.  My installs were clean (*install itself is the QA test*) so I'm guessing something else on your system has modified your defaults.

Comment: FYI:  I added `doublecmd-qt` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/doublecmd-qt) to the *groovy* install and didn't notice anything other than `pcmanfm-qt` opening (even with various settings changed in `doublecmd-qt` & programs exited & restarted).  Ideally I'd have used *focal* (so same version of LXQt) but that box is elsewhere.  In your case, esp. if you know when the change occurred (as I can't re-create it), I'd look for files (ie. `find -mtime` etc) modified around that date & look for *conf* (configuration type) changes that you can reverse.

Comment: Thanks a lot @guiverc for spending time to help me. I realize that I can reproduce this situation. Please see my new answer below. Thanks.

Comment: Lubuntu contains the setup created by the Lubuntu team (both Lubuntu LXQt & Openbox configuration options).  The LXQt setup however doesn't include this setup, and is a purer upstream LXQt experience; however because it's missing some Openbox configurations (upstream doesn't assume `openbox`) some behaviors aren't ideal as packaged, and a number of things the Lubuntu manual (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/) says will work, won't of course work because the Lubuntu scripts aren't used in the LXQt session.  The Lubuntu team support only the Lubuntu session.

Comment: Thanks. I understand, but I am not sure if is it bug to send them. I think it is just problem of configuration. Right?

Comment: If you want to file a bug, I'll add my findings to it, however I'd not expect much. We (*Lubuntu team*) support only the Lubuntu session, the LXQt session would need a lot more testing & proof it's not just a Lubuntu/Ubuntu/LXQt issue (I usually test on debian, opensuse & fedora too), plus it would need to be a later LXQt (ideally 15.1).  You may get answers here, my primary interest though was the Lubuntu session (which doesn't have the issue you've now indicated). You could also try the Lubuntu discourse site (*devs* frequent there & know way more of the stack than I do).